# Shortening a clause after the the word "other"

Tags: clauses

I want to write this following sentence using a shorter form.

> This process resulted in two lists: one is the group of variable A that are influenced by the variable X, and the other is the group of variable A that are influenced by the variable Y.

I think the clause "the group of variable A" can be shorten but I don't know how. 
Anybody can help?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Given that "group of variable A" is common for both lists, I would suggest:

> This process resulted in two groups of variable A: one influenced by the variable X, and the other by Y.